# Navigation bar Large Titles are shrunk if data is loaded off-screen through an Rx datasource binding

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

When using large titles in the navigation bar along with a UITableView that is bound to an Rx driver data source I’ve noticed that if the binding and initial data load happens while the view is offscreen, when you navigate to that view it will be scrolled such that the large title is shrunk to the “minimized” position.

Overall setup is a UITableViewController with `prefersLargeTitles = true` set. Tableview is setup and subsequently bound to the Rx datasource within `viewDidLoad`.

Example code:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  setupTableView()
  bindToTableView()

  // ...
}

private func setupTableView() {
  tableView.register(cellType: Cell.self)
  tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
  tableView.separatorStyle = .none

  // ...

  // We are required to first reset the data source and delegate to allow
  // for RxCocoa to take over control.
  tableView.dataSource = nil
  tableView.delegate = nil
  tableView.rx.setDelegate(self)
    .disposed(by: bag)

  // ...
}

private func bindToModel() {
  viewModel.modelDriver
    .drive(tableView.rx.items) { tableView, row, model in
      let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)
      let cell: Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath)
      cell.prepare(with: model)
      return cell
    }.disposed(by: bag)
}
```

And by "shrunk" I mean the titles switch to this style:

[image: small nav title]

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

---

**Solved:** As @daniel-t mentions below the problem is not caused by Rx specifically, but by the timing of when `prefersLargeTitles = true`. If this property is not set **before** the call to `tableView.reloadData()` occurs then the table will load in the data and scroll appropriately *for non-large titles*. Then after large titles is set the tableview doesn't reset it's scroll position to compensate for the new, larger navigation bar area.

The reason this manifests somewhat weirdly, even when using something like `.skipUntil(...viewWillAppear)`, is because the act of binding triggers an initial Rx update which reloads the tableview.

Comment: same issue ... any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is elsewhere, not in the code you presented or anything to do with Rx. The following works as intended:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    private let bag = DisposeBag()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = "Title"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.dataSource = nil
        tableView.delegate = nil
        tableView.rx.setDelegate(self)
            .disposed(by: bag)

        let modelDriver = Driver.just(Array<String>(repeating: "Hello world", count: 30))
        modelDriver
            .drive(tableView.rx.items) { tableView, row, model in
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)
                let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
                cell.textLabel?.text = model
                return cell
            }
            .disposed(by: bag)
    }
}
```

Maybe the problem has to do with how you are constructing your cells? Or maybe you are scrolling to the bottom of the list somewhere?